# Mathematical packages that can be used from .NET

Tags: .net, mathematical-packages

which are some mathematical packages that can be used from C#? I know about Lutz Roeder's Mapack package, do you know about similar packages? I am mainly interested of numerical analysis: numerical integration, linear and non-linear equations solving.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Some free libraries:

- Meta.Numerics ([www.meta-numerics.net](http://www.meta-numerics.net), [metanumerics.codeplex.com](http://metanumerics.codeplex.com))
- Math.NET ([numerics.mathdotnet.com](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com))
- dnAnalytics ([dnanalytics.codeplex.com](http://dnanalytics.codeplex.com))
- ILNumerics.NET ([ilnumerics.net](http://ilnumerics.net))

A proprietary library:

- Extreme Optimization ([www.extremeoptimization.com](http://www.extremeoptimization.com))

I am the architect of the Meta.Numerics library. It addresses your main interests with APIs for numerical integration, root-finding, and minimization/maximazation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Iridium package:

[Iridium package](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[NAG](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/DT/DTdescription.asp) also have a library, currently in Beta.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a library but a useful class when dealing with large numbers: [BigInteger](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx).